# How to get data from an API using Swift

Tags: json, swift, github-api

I'm trying to get data from an API into my table view, but app goes into the catch error " json error". I'll share the code with you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!
    
    var repository = [RepositoryStats]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadJSON {
            self.homeTableView.reloadData()
        }
        homeTableView.delegate = self
        homeTableView.dataSource = self
    }
    

    func downloadJSON (completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        
        let url = URL (string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Swift+language:RXSwift&sort=stars&order=desc")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                do {
                self.repository = try JSONDecoder().decode([RepositoryStats].self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                }catch {
                    print ("json error")
                }
            
        }
        }.resume()

}
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return repository.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = repository[indexPath.row].full_name
        return cell
    }
```

This is my struct where I declared :

```
struct RepositoryStats: Decodable {
        let items: [Item]
    
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    let fullName: String
}
```

If anyone know, why I am getting into the "json error" catch ? Thank you !

Link : https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Swift+language:RXSwift&sort=stars&order=desc

Comment: You are getting it because you are printing a hard coded string! If you want a proper and helpful error message then do `print(error)` in the `catch` clause. A quick glance at the json tells me you are missing a root element, you can’t start decoding from the middle of a json message. You need a type that corresponds to the top (or outermost if you prefer) elements of the message.

Comment: I used print(error) and I got this." xpected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))". I think that I need to do something with that "items", if you open the link, is some thing like : "items" : [ and after is the full_name. Can you help me out with that ?

Comment: This is what I tried to explain in the first comment. Create a new type that contains items which is an array of your type. Then use this new type when using JSONDecoder

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have changed my struct, but I got the same error .

Comment: RepositoryStats is an array?

Comment: You forgot to change the decoding call most likely, `JSONDecoder().decode(RepositoryStats.self, …`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I have changed my struct into this :

```
struct RepositoryStats: Decodable {
    let items: [Item]
    
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    let full_name: String
    let forks_count: Int
    let stargazers_count: Int
}
```

And this is my downloaad JSON func.

```
func downloadJSON (completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    
    let url = URL (string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Swift+language:RXSwift&sort=stars&order=desc")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.repository = try JSONDecoder().decode(RepositoryStats.self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }catch {
                print (error)
            }
        
    }
    }.resume()
```

}
}